# How can I have a user verify if they are connected to a domain?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, active-directory

I'm looking for a client-side method of confirming whether or not a user is connected and fully integrated into an active directory domain.

I know users can type **echo %userdomain% %username%** but does that actually confirm the state of their connection? Or does it just return their login details?

-M

Answer (score 2):

"Connected" and "fully integrated" are somewhat open to interpretation, but at a command prompt perhaps try:

```
net config workstation
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the command `whoami` ?

When I'm the local system admin

```
C:\>whoami
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
```

Or (when I on the PDC)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>whoami
CORP\Username
```

**Update**
I just realised that whoami is not a standard command (except in Vista+).

For older versions of Windows :

1. It's part of the "Windows XP SP2 Support Tools"
2. Was before in the "Windows 2000 Resource Kit".